# Why don't rails commands run in eshell?

Tags: eshell

I am a total emacs newbie and am trying to figure my way around emacs(I am kinda liking it).
Now my question is that when I type rails commands in my terminal, they work perfectly well.

```
user ~ $ rails -v
Rails 4.2.1
```

But when I run the same commands in eshell, I get:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~/.emacs.d $ rails -v
rails: command not found
```

To my understanding, eshell is a shell within emacs. Right? Or I have it completely wrong?

Comment: Emacs uses PATH as defined by the environment it was started from. If you've changed PATH only in your shell, it will obviously not work.

Comment: @wasamasa How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eshell does not run your default shell, so it will ignore whatever you have set up in the shell rc script.

You can set environment variables in `~/.eshell/login` or `~/.eshell/profile`, use `addpath PATH` (for some string value of `PATH`), or add a hook to evaluate `(setenv ...)` with the appropriate values.

For a more regular shell I recommend using `M-x shell`, which just communicates with an external shell process.